# How to access attachment data programmatically in outlook if attachment is itself a mail

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

I am programmatically trying to get the attachment data in C# in following way :--

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Attachment attachment = objMail.Attachments[attachmentIndex];

if (attachment.DisplayName.Equals("Test"))

{ 

   const string PR_ATTACH_DATA = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37010102";

    byte[] attachmentData = attachment.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty(PR_ATTACH_DATA);

}
```

Now my code is working fine if attachment is text file or image file. But if attachment is itself a mail, it throws the exception that property is unknown or can not be found.

Please suggest in which cases / type of attachments, this property "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x37010102" will not work and in those cases, what would be alternative property / method to get the attachment data in byte array ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

`PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN` is only present for the regular by-value attachments (`PR_ATTACH_METHOD == ATTACH_BY_VALUE`). Embedded message or OLE attachments do not expose that property - they use `PR_ATTACH_DATA_OBJ` which must be opened using `IAttach::OpenProperty(IID_IStorage, ...)` - take a look at the existing messages using [OutlookSpy](http://www.dimastr.com/outspy) - I am its author - select the message, click IMessage button, go to GetAttachmentTable tab, double click on the attachment.

Also keep in mind that `PropertyAccessor.GetProperty` would only be able to retrieve that property for small attachments. For large attachments, `PR_ATTACH_DATA_BIN` must be opened as `IStream` using `IAttach::OpenProperty(IID_IStorage, ...)` - `PropertyAccessor.GetProperty` does not do that. You will need to use Extended MAPI (C++ or Delphi) or [Redemption](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption) (I am its author) - it exposes [RDOAttachment](http://www.dimastr.com/redemption/RDOAttachment.htm).`AsArray` / `AsText` / `AsStream` properties.

Comment: Hi Dmitry, Thanks for reply. Can you please provide me some example, how can I call IAttach::OpenProperty from C# code ? It would be great help for me.

Comment: You can't - as I mentioned, Extended MAPI is C++ or Delphi only.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Graph Rest API is an single end point and wrapper for most Microsoft Data including events, most office products including outlook. Best of all any language can make a request to the endpoint and retrieve the information. See the complete Docs [HERE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview?view=graph-rest-1.0) to get started.

See below code for a simple Get request for outlook attachments. Note there are other more complex implementations. Docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/attachment-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http Scroll through the link and you can find C#, Java, and JavaScript examples on how to implement this.

```
GET /me/messages/{id}/attachments/{id}
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages/{id}/attachments/{id}

GET /me/messages/{id}/attachments/{id}/$value
GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/messages/{id}/attachments/{id}/$value
```